# Bottom border without text in div

Tags: html, css

I want to create  border-bottom. And I try this

```
<div class="borderblog"></div>

.borderblog{
border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

but this only work if i put some text in that div. like this

```
 <div class="borderblog">text</div>
```

and i don't want to put any text there. I only want to have one line dotted border bottom.
I also try to use HR tags but it don't work.

[Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jj2L4/)

Comment: why you use a `DIV` to simulate another DIV's border?

Comment: Just updated the answer to apply the border to `<hr>` element instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can set div height to one like:

```
.borderblog{
 height: 1px;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

Div is block element and if it doesn't have any context the height is 0 and border is not visible because border is inside div. Width is not needed, since block element fills parent (container) width as default.

Answer (score 3):

set height and width

```
.borderblog{
border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
width:20px;
height:1px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/R5RRY/)

Comment: it s more flexible like that you have he control on how long it will be

Comment: ok, and it's not flexible that it matches the space dynamically.. for example when resizing browser window.. you know responsive..:)

Comment: well for that you are correct but for responsive i will better use css calc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc , percentage or em it s up to you (note that my answer is based on the question "Bottom border without text in div")

Answer (score 1):

Well, [it works for me](http://jsbin.com/tadagiqa/1/edit) on IE8, FF9 and Chrome32.

However, you can use `<hr>` element to create the dotted line as follows:

```
<hr class="borderblog">
```

```css
.borderblog {
    border: 0; /* <-- Reset the useragent stylesheet at first */
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/Jj2L4/1/)**.

---

Also, If you need a solid border and if by any reason the previous approaches didn't work for you, you can use background color for a `1px`-height div

```css
.borderblog {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/jufoqoxo/1/edit)**.

In this case you can add a `border-bottom` as well, to make it 3D visually.

**[Updated Demo](http://jsbin.com/jufoqoxo/2/edit)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
div does not have any height width by default, unless you specify it
```

so when you add text it gets some value and is shown, so the bordering is applied

```
.borderblog{
 height: 1px;
 border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do, just put height and width in css:

```
.borderblog{
    width:100px; //depends what width border you want
    height:1px; //depends what height you want, 1px is enought for border only
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

And this is it, no need for text within :)